# Visual Defects on Scrolling to Div

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a new jQuery form framework and have run into a weird styling issue:

http://www.jformer.com/demos/page-navigator/

When sliding to the next page the div floated to the left of it starts wigging out during the slide. Does anyone know what might be causing this? This bug is in Firefox 3.

Comment: How about providing a little more downcut sample? You are including over 20js files there and 4css files nobody is going to debug all that

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: just fyi your buttons have a scrollbar in opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping elements in a div styled "overflow: auto" fixed the issue. Any elements positioned absolutely in a scrolling container are going to wig out.